# Order complex object

Tags: c#, linq, odata

I require to do complex queries, such as the following:

```
(from e in _dataContext.Entity.Expand("RelationA/RelationB")
select e)
.OrderBy(x => x.RelationA.RelationB.Property)
.ThenBy(x => x.RelationA.Property)
.ThenBy(x => x.Property)
.Skip(0).Take(10);
```

or

```
(from e in _dataContext.Entity.Expand("RelationA/RelationB")
orderby e.RelationA.RelationB.Property, e.RelationA.Property, e.Property
select e)
.Skip(0).Take(10);
```

The above gives me a server error, saying that the process could not be performed.

In the case of order only by the first relationship and property there is no problem, is when I put two relationships in the order.

The server side use: Microsoft.Data.Services 5.6.0.0

Use client-side: Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.4.0

It is possible to perform this type of queries, or is something out of place, thanks.

Stack Trace:

```
   en System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   en System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
   en System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   en System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   en System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   en Sigap.Wpf.ViewModel.GenLocalidadListViewModel.ObtenerPaginado()
```

More information about the error:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code /><m:message xml:lang="es-MX">An error occurred while processing this request.</m:message><m:innererror><m:message>No se pudo aplicar formato al nodo 'OptionalValue' para su ejecución como SQL.</m:message><m:type>System.InvalidOperationException</m:type><m:stacktrace>   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitOptionalValue(SqlOptionalValue sov)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitSearchedCase(SqlSearchedCase c)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitWithParens(SqlNode node, SqlNode outer)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitUnaryOperator(SqlUnary uo)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitSearchedCase(SqlSearchedCase c)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitWithParens(SqlNode node, SqlNode outer)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitUnaryOperator(SqlUnary uo)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitSearchedCase(SqlSearchedCase c)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitRowNumber(SqlRowNumber rowNumber)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitRow(SqlRow row)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect ss)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias alias)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect ss)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.Format(SqlNode node, Boolean isDebug)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Format(SqlNode node)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(ResultShape resultShape, Type resultType, SqlNode node, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parentParameters, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()&#xD;
   en System.Data.Services.Internal.ProjectedWrapper.EnumerableWrapper.GetEnumerator()&#xD;
   en System.Data.Services.WebUtil.GetRequestEnumerator(IEnumerable enumerable)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Services.QueryResultInfo.MoveNext()&#xD;
   en System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService, IODataResponseMessage responseMessage)&#xD;
   en System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()</m:stacktrace></m:innererror></m:error>
```

Comment: What are the relationship for each one of them? Are they all 1:1 relationship?

Comment: The relationships are 1 : N ! 
a State has many municipalities, where municipality is the Entity and  State the relationship; and the relationship b is for countries

Comment: what is the stack trace?

Comment: can you provide actual code that you have and that you tried and it works?

Comment: what are the possible values for properties that you are trying to filter on? can some of them be null?

Comment: Hi, I'll try to make a project more small, and not possible null values in the order or filter. It apparently does not support many relationships, because I can put more than two sentences, provided it does not exceed two levels in the query !